# automation of web tasks

Tags: language-agnostic, web

This question pertains to this link:

http://aeronav.faa.gov/afd.asp?cycle=afd_26JUL2012&eff=07-26-2012&end=09-20-2012#results

To give you some background, I have no experience in Web Programming. I am however decently versed in C/C++, but I don't mind learning a Web language/s to do what I need to do.

The link above contains a form to select an airport. Once an airport is chosen and the search link is clicked, the page scrolls down and a link to download a pdf file containing information about the airport is populated.

Now, the task: I have an excel sheet that contains a list of airports (and of course the fields required to navigate to the airport with the form such as city, name and state).

I would like to implement a script/program that automatically populates the fields in the above link with the information in the excel sheet for each airport, and downloads the resulting pdf link to a specified location locally. If a tool for doing something like this already exists, I would obviously prefer to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One scripting language you could use for this is [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Using this, you can script where the mouse should move to, what the keyboard should type, and control it all. You would have to play around with the timing since some of the searches and downloading will take longer than others.

However, rather than typing in the different information into the web form each time, if you could determine what naming convention they use for the .pdf files, you could possibly save some time.

Or you could download each of the .pdf pages from the books, and then run a program to get the file you are interested in for a specific airport. (you could use auto-it to do the downloading. I would probably use c# and the WebBrowser object, but I'm use to c#).

For instance, according to the north-west [legend](http://aeronav.faa.gov/pdfs/nw_front_26JUL2012.pdf), the table of contents list Idaho from pages 22 through 61 (inclusive).

which may mean that you could just pre-download:

```
http://aeronav.faa.gov/pdfs/nw_22_26JUL2012.pdf
http://aeronav.faa.gov/pdfs/nw_23_26JUL2012.pdf
http://aeronav.faa.gov/pdfs/nw_24_26JUL2012.pdf
...
http://aeronav.faa.gov/pdfs/nw_61_26JUL2012.pdf
```

then go on to Montana, etc.

Searching for a specific airport in Idaho, would involve searching through the Idaho .pdf files for the name of the airport.

Anyway, that's probably how I would go about it.